# In Python, how can I store the last element of a list?

Tags: python, list

Say I have the list x = []. I need to keep track of the last element in that list. I could do this with the variable last = x[-1], but of course this gives an index error if x is empty. How can I account for this so that I don't get an error when x is empty?

Comment: What do you want `last` to reference when the list is empty?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
 last = x[-1] if x else None
```

Put whatever you want in case of an empty list in place of None.

Comment: Wouldn't `last = x[-1] if x[-1] else None` be better?

Comment: @johnthexiii No, that would suffer from the same problem as just using `last = x[-1]`. The `if x` is designed to make sure `x` has at least one element in it, because an empty list is considered logically false.

Comment: @johnthexiii, You could check for `if x[-1:]`, but I ythink `if x` is clearer anyway

Answer (score 3):

You could try `x[-1:]` which returns a *list* containing either the last element, or an empty list if `x` is the empty list. Of course, if you want to use that element for something, you'll still have to check to see whether it is present or not.